# How to validate reference use?

Tags: language-design, validation, reference

*I use "reference" term here like in C++ world, not like in C# (for example). I use non-C++ syntax on purpose -- this is general question, not about this particular implementation.*

Starting something like C++ afresh I would like to make rules and validation in order to prevent a case when reference outlives its source. For example this looks like a valid usage:

```
def foo(x ref int) ref int
    return x;
end
```

But this is wrong:

```
def bar() ref int
    x int = 5;
    return x;
end
```

because in `bar` example `x` is put on stack and when reference to it is returned this stack is already gone.

I didn't so far find the analysis algorithm description so that is why I am asking -- what to allow (for example defining parameters as references), and how to check when the usage is abused creating dangling references?

Comment: Be careful when saying things like "is put on stack."  In languages like C# and Java, the "stack" is *an implementation detail.*  In those languages, you're not supposed to know or care whether items like `x` go onto the stack or the heap, and ultimately this is a scope problem, not a stack problem.

Comment: I suspect that your declaration in the second code example isn't even possible in C#; it would be a compile error.  `int` in C# is a primitive type, not an object (reference), and it's perfectly acceptable to create an `int` and return it (by value) in C#.

Comment: Finally, mechanisms like closures and state machines make it possible for local variables to live beyond their enclosing scope.

Comment: Your examples are simple and can be solved with an *escape analysis*. But there can be far more tricky constellations that are not solvable with a C++-style type system (the compiler would have to solve the halting problem). Take a very good look at Rust's ownership tracking instead: every reference is parametrized by a lifetime. The type system can check that no reference can outlive the lifetime of it's object.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, it seems like you think in terms of C#, not C++. References in C# are different things, and as for closures it depends how they are built (in C# by capturing the variables).

Comment: @amon, thank you very much, my preorder of "Programming Rust" is finally on its way ;-)

Comment: Any automatic local variable will go out of scope as or before function return, so a *reference* to one shouldn't be returned as in theory it might already be destroyed.  Parameters will go out of scope as well, *but if the parameter is a ref parameter*, then it is essentially bound to some variable passed by the caller, who controls its scope.

Comment: You stated specifically that your question was not C++ specific.

Comment: If your parser knows if a variable is locally defined or not, then you can solve this problem by checking if the returned address is of a local variable.  Does your language allow an expression to be returned (allowing offsets of pointer references)?  If so, the issue becomes a bit more complex as you can imagine..

Comment: Have you looked at [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/)? It is a language with exactly the design goals you state.

Comment: @Neil, I am afraid my issue is a bit more complex, because I would like to have references to fields returned (for C#-like properties) and I also realized it would be great to have references in fields (.ie. the field is of type "reference to int" for example) -- but this makes analysis even harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called *escape analysis*, and like pretty much all static analysis of programs is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

It can only be solved in restricted circumstances, in particular, it is much easier to solve if the language is *specifically* designed in such a way as to restrict the kinds of programs that can be written to that subset which is amenable to static escape analysis.

Comment: Ah the Halting Problem.  Pretty much any mildly interesting fact you could ever hope to know about a program however insignificant is impossible to generalize.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a low-level language, there is nothing you can do to stop [dangling pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer), [null pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer), [circular references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference), and [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). The best you can do is provide a [memory debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_debugger) to help track down bugs.

On the other hand, if you are creating a higher-level language, then you can stop all these problems by not allowing programmers direct access to pointers. An example of this is the POSIX [`ln`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ln.html) command. A user cannot use it to hard link directories; only the root user can. A user simply cannot any of the problems with pointers.